# Config format in Go project

Tags: go

The most common formats for config file are json, yaml and etc.
When we use this formats, we need to open the file and parse it into structure.
Can we declare config like a new go package and export necessary data by variables? Are there any problems or pitfalls?

Comment: Thank u 4 dislikes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main disadvantage is that you have to ship the Go compiler and linker as part of your configuration system, because in order to load a configuration file, you have to compile the configuration file and link it into the application.

You also have to make sure that the ABI of the compiled configuration file is compatible with the ABI of the application.